# Using subquery in poco to fill property

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, poco

I am trying to use a property on a POCO that uses LINQ to ENTITY to pull the first object out of a HashSet property on the same POCO.  My object contains the following:

```
public virtual HashSet<ScheduleWaypoint> ScheduleWaypoints { get; set; }

public ScheduleWaypoint ArrivalStation {
        get {
            if (this.ScheduleWaypoints != null && this.ScheduleWaypoints.Count() > 0) {
                return this.ScheduleWaypoints.Where(row => row.WaypointType.Type.Trim() == "SA").OrderByDescending(row => row.ScheduledTime).First();
            } else
                return null;
        }
    }
```

If I were working with just one object I can't say for certain if this would work but I know that it does not work inside other linq queries. I don't have access to the ID of the ScheduleWaypoint when creating the object, only after it is populated could I possibly do that.  Is there a way that I can get this to work?  Right now it is telling me:

> The specified type member 'ArivalStation' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation
>   properties are supported.

Is there something I can do to get access to this information on a property rather than constantly doing joins when I need the info?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use custom properties in linq-to-entities query. Only properties mapped directly to the database can be used = you must have sub query directly in your linq-to-entities query returning your `ArrivalStation`. Perhaps it can be wrapped as simple extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<ScheduleWaypoint> GetArrivalStation(this IQueryable<ScheduleWaypoints> waypoints, int routeId)
{
    return waypoints.Where(w => w.WaypointType.Type.Trim() == "SA" && w.Route.Id == routeId)
                    .OrderByDescending(w => w.ScheduledTime)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Where `Route` is your principal entity where way points are defined. `FirstOrDefault` is used because sub queries cannot use just `First`.

Comment: I figured I was under some constraint like that but didn't know what it was.  I don't know if that solution will work for me though.  If I return an IQueryable I can't use it during the where clause when working with a field on ArrivalStation and I can't do a join on it because I don't have access to the first "from" in the linq to pass as a parameter.   If I had a collection of schedules and I needed all of their ArrivalStations, can you see a way to accomplish that with this method?